# Multiple condition based on where clause in sql server 2008

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, where-clause

I had a table `Product` with these columns

```
ProductName,
Description,
Manufacturer,
Product Code,
Technology,
Address,
Country,
City,
Length
```

I want to search all these fields with these criteria

- SearchType='Contains'
- SearchType='Ends'
- SearchType='Equals'
- SearchType='Greater'
- SearchType='Less'
- SearchType='Not Equal'
- SearchType='Like'

Another parameter I will pass whether to use AND/OR operation

At a time we can search 6 columns with any of the search criteria and AND\OR operation

the condition in where clause will be like this

```
WHERE (ProductName = @ProductName) AND (Country Like @Country +%) OR
      (ManufacturerLikre(Ends) '%' + @Manufacturer ) AND (Length < (Greater) @Length)
```

So the user can input 6 conditions based on the above criteria.

Can you help to get the logic for where clause

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps the easiest solution is to build it dynamically in your front end code using the following format:

WHERE whereClause1 AND/OR whereClause2 AND/OR whereClause3...etc

Substitute whereClause1, etc. with relevant sql syntax and each AND/OR. To cope with all possible AND/OR combinations you need to provide a way of grouping the where clauses with brackets otherwise it restricts possible range of combinations and also assumes user user understands precedence of AND and OR operators.

Also, you'd need to be aware of possible SQL injection attack when building queries from user input.

Answer (score 0):

If i have got the question right, I think you want o combine the condition and then USE **`OR`**

```
 WHERE ((ProductName = @ProductName) AND (Country Like @Country +%)) OR
       ^(Extra Brackets to combine) 
      ((ManufacturerLikre(Ends) '%' + @Manufacturer ) AND (Length < (Greater) @Length))
      ^(Extra Brackets to combine)
```